# Why doesn't compile-time exception division by zero produce at Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, divide-by-zero

Please check below codes ...

```
    // this will produce java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    System.out.println(1 / 0);
    // this will produce Infinity result
    System.out.println(1.1 / 0);
```

I assume **Integer** arithmetic will always throws **java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero**. If so , I guess the first statement or `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1") / 0);` should produce *compile-time exception*. But I didn't get any compile time errors or warnnings on my **Eclipse IDE**. Or may be I am wrong.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the relation with C++? The GCC compiler would probably have warned you....

Comment: @Raxvan sorry I have edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt("1")` will only be executed at runtime. The compiler doesn't know if the parse operation would even succeed.

Depending on the compiler `1/0` might get optimized at compile time and the compiler might just write the result into the compiled code. Hence it would throw the exception right there. However, if that calculation isn't optimized, the compiler wouldn't know the result of that operation until it is executed.

Btw, my Eclipse compiler doesn't seem to do that (I didn't check the settings yet) and compiles `1/0` just fine.

**UPDATE**

Although `1/0` would be a constant expression which can be evaluated at compile time, the compiler might still opt to ignore that and compile the code.

Here's some a similar question with some more info: [Why doesn't a Java constant divided by zero produce compile time error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980360/why-doesnt-a-java-constant-divided-by-zero-produce-compile-time-error)

Comment: `1/0` using literals is guaranteed to run and thus would surely cause an exception or might even be calcuated at compile time for optizations while parsing a string first might fail even before the division by zero would be executed.

Comment: I am sure my Eclipse IDE doesn't appear any errors or warnnings for statement `1/0`. Is it true for java compiler ?

Comment: @Cataclysm as I stated in my edit it depends on the compiler and there might be reasons to not throw an exception at compile time.

Comment: fine ! Now I have satisfied with your updated answer. Thanks for your good answer and useful links.