# Computation of string at run time and compile time

Tags: java, literals

I found that the constant literal is computed at compile time for example:`int a=10+20;` but when i try to use `int b=10/0;` i find that it is computed at run time.
Can you please tell me why this constant literal is computed at run time?
Thank you.

Comment: Division by zero!! May god be with us...

Comment: He is farseer, has a null talisman that allows divison by zero

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is 1/0 a legal Java expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934063/is-1-0-a-legal-java-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constant value MAY be computed at compile time, if the compiler can maintain the same semantics as if it were done at run time.  If not (eg, the case of divide by zero) then it defers the computation to run time. For more info read [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).