# Why doesn't java compiler show a warning for an obvious dividing by zero?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

This is just my curiosity to know why java compiler doesn't show any warning in this case while it shows warning for unchecked operations to predict a probable ClassCastException.

```
public class DivideByZero {
    public static void main() {
        int number = 3/0;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Above code is guaranteed to produce an ArithmeticException.

This is an example only.
There are more ways to guarantee a runtime exception without any warning during compilation.

Comment: Because the Java compiler is not infinitely smart.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934063/is-1-0-a-legal-java-expression

Comment: Because the compiler can't dictate what is "wrong" and what is "right".You may think division by zero is wrong, but some other people could think otherwise. Getting a warning in this case, therefore, would be annoying to them.

Answer (score 3):

Because technically a divide by zero is a valid program. Compilers only determine the validity of the program not whether there will be a runtime problem. It would be technically incorrect for a compiler to not let you compile a program with a divide by zero since it's valid.

Comment: That's exactly why he's asking for a _warning_.

Comment: @SLaks missed the part about a warning :\

Comment: @SLaks Why would he want a warning about perfectly valid and proper use of code?   That would be more a job for something akin to checkstyle.

Comment: For example, a possible classcast exception is worth a warning because it's potentially bad programming. Whereas dividing by zero is not.